# Refreshing the socket.io request object

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, passport.js

How can I refresh/populate the `socket.request.session.passport` object in Node.js with an Ajax call?

I've tried re-connecting the sockets after an Ajax call to no avail. It seems that this object on the server is only refreshed after a page load, suggesting the socket.io client library reads cookies in the browser when it loads, and never looks at them again.

I'm using Express, passport.js, and socket.io.

Comment: `socket.request` comes from the state when the socket.io connection is created.  If you kill the socket.io object on the client and create an entirely new one, you should get a new connection on the server and a new `socket.request` on the server.  You may just want to look at how to better use passport and socket.io together here: https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio

Comment: Yeah, it never looks at cookies again because cookies are only sent with the socket.io connection.  No cookies are ever sent again as long as the connection stays connected since once it's connected with the original HTTP request (that has cookies on it), all future communication is just webSocket/socket.io packets.  No cookies are sent when communicating via socket.io messages.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jfriend00 the solution was to destroy the object on the client and create a new one.

```js
mysocket.disconnect()
mysocket = io()
```